# INSERTing values into a child table referenced from parent table

Tags: mysql, parent-child, composite-primary-key, insert-into, junction-table

I was up all last night trying to crack this but with no luck so I'm hoping you guys can help as I'm all out of ideas:

I have two parent tables that I want to populate a Junction table from:

**Brides:**

```
create table if not exists `Brides` ( 
    `BrideID` INT not null auto_increment,
    `MaidenName` varchar(10) unique,
    primary key (`BrideID`)
   ) engine=InnoDB;

    insert into Brides (MaidenName)
    values ('Smith'),
           ('Jones')
    ;
```

**Churches:**

```
create table if not exists `Churches` (
`ChurchID` INT not null auto_increment,
`ChurchName` varchar(10) unique,
primary key (`ChurchID`)
) engine=InnoDB;

insert into Churches (ChurchName)
values ('St Marys'),
       ('St Albans')
;
```

---

I am trying to populate the ID variables for Junction table **Marriages** by indirectly referencing the unique names in each parent table. In addition, I'm looking to include `MarriedName` to identify if a Bride marries more than once:

**Marriages:**

```
create table if not exists 'Marriages' (
'BrideID' INT not null,
'ChurchID' INT not null,
'MarriedName' TEXT not null
primary key ('BrideID','ChurchID','MarriedName')
  INDEX `fk_Marriages_Brides1_idx` (`BrideID` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_Marriages_Churches1_idx` (`ChurchID` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Marriages_Brides1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`BrideID`)
    REFERENCES `Brides` (`BrideID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Marriages_Churches1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Church_ID`)
    REFERENCES `Churches` (`ChurchID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
;
```

I'm trying to do something like the below pseudo-code (although I'm pretty sure it wouldn't be the smart way to do it anyway as must be slow with with so many sub-queries):

```
insert into Marriages (Bride_ID, Church_ID, MarriedName)
  select b.BrideID, c.ChurchID, m.MarriedName
  from (values (Bride,Church,MarriedName)
         ('Smith','St Marys','Johnson'),
         ('Jones','St Albans','Peterson')
         ) m

  join Brides b
  on a.MaidenName=m.Bride
  join Churches c
  on m.Church=c.ChurchName;
```

Any help/insight/corrections you have would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for completeness, I wanted to share this solution in case it helps anyone else....First and last step requires no changes and just the 'raw' data in the second step needs adding to:

```
create table if not exists `_marriages` (
  `BrideName` varchar(10) null,
  `ChurchName` varchar(10) null,
  `MarriedName` varchar(10)  NULL,
 primary key (`BrideName`,`ChurchName`,`MarriedName`))
 engine=InnoDB
;

insert into `_marriages` (BrideName,ChurchName,MarriedName)
  values 
    ('Smith','St Albans','Johnson'),
    ('Jones','St Marys','Peterson')
;

insert into `Marriages` (Bride_ID, Church_ID, MarriedName)
select distinct b.BrideID, c.ChurchID, a.MarriedName
from _marriages a
inner join Brides b
  on (a.BrideName=b.MaidenName)
left join Churches c
  on a.ChurchName=c.ChurchName
;
```

...as always though, if anyone has any advancement on a better way to do it please let us know!

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
INSERT INTO Marriages
SELECT b.BrideID, c.ChurchID, 'Johnson'
FROM Brides b, Churches c
WHERE b.MaidenName='Smith' AND c.ChurchName='St Marys'
```

Comment: lol - sorry about previous comment....I've updated my original question with the pseudo code in the hope you know if it's possible....! I was hoping to be able to bulk enter some records which is nice and clear to enter with VALUE statements. Thanks again.

Comment: When you say you are using load statements, do you mean you are importing from a CSV (or similar)?

Comment: Yes - for my parent tables I am loading records from CSV files but now I've hit a wall as I can't work out how to start populating the tables which have dependencies on the parent tables (these parent tables are still 'evolving' in the meantime as I flesh out the test data so I can't create CSV files referencing specific key ID variables)

Comment: I don't think you can refer to existing tables within a `LOAD DATA` query. I think you'd need to load the marriages data into a temporary table and then update your Marriages table from there.